# Use macs alias folders in R

Tags: r, macos, directory-structure

I am playing around with my data storage structure and thought it a great idea to have one folder with original data and distribute it from there to r project folders via an alias folder. But it seems R doest understand alias folders as it shows it as an object but but a folder.
Is there a nice way to solve this or should I simply use my mail folder as a working directory of each project and get the scripts via subfolder structures?

Google seems oblivious to this question so I thought maybe someone here can help :)

Thanks!
Sebastian

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using cross-platform symbolic links vs the macOS native alias files created via Finder operations. Go to a Terminal/iTerm prompt and do:

```
$ man ln
```

to learn more.

However, you *can* work with macOS alias files from R. The version 3 binary alias file format is still kinda opaque and I didn't feel like digging into binary formats on a rainy November afternoon but you can use the `mactheknife` package to accomplish this via applescript:

```
library(mactheknife) # github or gitlab hrbrmstr/mactheknife

resolve_alias <- function(path) {
  mactheknife::applescript(sprintf('
set myPosix to POSIX file "%s"
tell application "Finder"
   set myPath to original item of item myPosix
end tell
set myPOSIXPath to POSIX path of (myPath as text)
return myPOSIXPath
', path.expand(path)))
}

(resolve_alias("~/Desktop/data-alias"))
## [1] "/Users/bob/data/"
```

If you can't install that package for some reason (it has some heavy dependencies for some folks), here's the source code for the `applescript()` function:

```
applescript <- function (script_source, extra_args = c(), params = c()) {
  script_source <- paste0(script_source, collapse = "\n")
  tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".applescript")
  on.exit(unlink(tf), add = TRUE)
  cat(script_source, file = tf)
  osascript <- Sys.which("osascript")
  args <- c(extra_args, tf, params)
  res <- system2(command = osascript, args = args, stdout = TRUE)
  invisible(res)
}
```

which is all base R with no dependencies (outside of it being macOS-specific :-)

**UPDATE**

I added a `resolve_alias()` function *to* the `mactheknife` package so now you can just do:

```
mactheknife::resolve_alias("path-to-alias-file")
```

if you can install `mactheknife`.